# in ListView.setOnItemClickListener the (View)adapter.getChildAt(6); returns null

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`, whose every item (i.e `TextView`) is filled with Lyrics text of Song. Whenever i click an item it should be highlighted and previous selected item background should be changed to default. For this i use `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` as below:

```
public int songNo;
public int totalSongs;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyric_display);
                    songNo=0;
        totalSongs=7;
        ListView songLyricsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LyricDisplayListView);
        MediaPlayer soundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        songLyricsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View selectedView, int pos,
                    long arg3) {

                **//set background to older selection**
                View oldSelectedView;
                oldSelectedView = (View)adapter.getChildAt(songNo);
                oldSelectedView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

                songNo = pos;
                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

                songLyricsListView.smoothScrollToPosition(songNo);

                try {
                    soundPlayer.reset();
                    soundPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/0"+Integer.toString(songNo)+".mp3");
                    soundPlayer.prepare();
                    soundPlayer.start();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        });


    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    String[] from = new String[] {"lyrics","translation"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.songTextView, R.id.translationTextView};


    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lyric_text); 
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        int myInt=0;
        for(int songno=0; songno<=totalSongs; songno++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            ByteArrayBuffer myByteArray = new ByteArrayBuffer(100); 
            while((myInt = bis.read())!=-1)
            {
                if(myInt == 10) break;
                myByteArray.append((byte)myInt);
            }

            String lyricsText = new String(myByteArray.toByteArray(), 0, myByteArray.length(), "UTF-8");
            myByteArray.clear();
            map.put("lyrics",lyricsText);
            map.put("translation", Integer.toString(songno)+"-  sample translation");
            list.add((HashMap<String, String>)map);
        }
        bis.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter = new SpecialAdapter(
                            this, 
                            list, 
                            R.layout.lyrics_display_item, 
                            from, 
                            to );

    songLyricsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
        public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, items, resource, from, to);
        }

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      if(position == songNo)
      {
          view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

      }else
          view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
      return view;
    }
}
```

when i set bigger font size to list item, when i select 6th item and again i select 5th item, in the code line:

```
oldSelectedView = (View)adapter.getChildAt(songNo);
```

`oldSelectedView` is returned as `null`. But when i use small font, the list fits on a single screen and 6th item seletction and then 7th or 5th selection does't make any problem.

Please help me solve this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onItemClickListner() fixed the problem..

Answer (score 0):

It maybe has something todo with the ListAdapter not having the same position as your song number. Maybe using a custom list adapter and using an array solves the problem:
[link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

It's a sample of a custom list adapter in APIDemos

Comment: public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter { public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) { super(context, items, resource, from, to); }
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      if(position == songNo)
      {
          view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
      }else
          view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
      return view;
    }
} 
this is the code for SpecialAdapter, please review it i can't find any problem

Comment: my list adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onItemClickListner() fixes the problem for me!